# Is it possible to style the iron-autogrow-textarea scrollbar in Polymer 1.x?

Tags: css, webkit, polymer, scrollbar

I have tried standard styling techniques as well as mixins (`--iron-autogrow-textarea`) and I could not find a way to style the scrollbar (for the `textarea`) of this element using webkit-scrollbar styles, for example:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {...}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {...}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {...}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: it doesn't seem possible with the current defined mixin...

Answer (score 0):

So this is kind of awkward but you can drill down through the `paper-textarea` shadow dom to get to that scrollbar. **Warning:** shadow dom of Polymer components isn't guaranteed to not change between versions. So updating your `paper-textarea` from bower may break this.

```
paper-textarea/deep/ paper-input-container/deep/ iron-autogrow-textarea/deep/ div textarea::-webkit-scrollbar{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
}
```

[Demo Here (type in a few lines in the paper textarea)](http://codepen.io/dsschnau/pen/obXaZR?editors=110)

**Edit**
Great points in the comments. /deep/ is going away so this is guaranteed to break in the future. I'm not clear on how you could style this without a mixin available for specifically the scrollbar (which doesn't seem likely since its a webkit-only style to begin with).

Anyway, you could use an `iron-autogrow-textarea` instead of `paper-textarea` since it looks like you're not using any of the 'paper' styles from `paper-textarea`. That way the selector would be a bit less cumbersome since you wouldn't have to drill through `paper-textarea` and `paper-input-container`.

Comment: I'm assuming this would also be the case for using `iron-autogrow-textarea` without `paper-textarea`? I have opened this as an issue on GitHub - https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-autogrow-textarea/issues/60

Comment: /deep/ will be deprecated, see https://blog.polymer-project.org/announcements/2015/12/01/deprecating-deep/